# Get object from a string where string is containing the object in an array

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

Following is the data I am getting from a server:

```
let data = aa[0].innerHTML.trim();
```

Data:

```
[        
  {
    "userid" : "3455535",
    "roll_number" : "8845",
    "Attributes" :  {
    },
    "status" : "Fail",
    "barCode" : '5774777858'
  }
]
```

This data is `typeof string`

I want to extract the whole object from this string, I tried to use JSON.parse but its throwing error.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data))
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 326

I also tried (to replace [ & ] with '' and then trim but this is also not working)

```
console.log(data.replace(/[|]/, ''))
```

Let me know how can I extract the data.

Comment: I suggest you create a minimal test case. More often than not, this makes the error obvious.

Comment: Your data is not valid JSON. String values should be enclosed by double quotes `"` not single quotes `'`. Ideally the service that is serving up the data should be fixed so that it gives __valid__ JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace all occurrences of `'` with `"` in your JSON response.

```
data = data.replace(/\'/g, '"')
```

Comment: Thanks I am able to get the data now :)